# How to access multiple gmail accounts from the terminal

Tags: terminal, console, tmux

Is there a way to access several email accounts (gmail or yahoo) from the command line, I am using tmux

I want to be able to view received and send emails without accessing chrome or any other webbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pine`/`alpine`](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~csadmin/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_Pine_%28Alpine%29_for_IMAP_Gmail) or `lynx`.